# Powerpoint VBA to search for and change colour/highlight keywords in textbox

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I am very new to VB and am exploring this method to simplify mundane manual work process of highlighting certain text in Powerpoint textboxes.
My intention is for VBA to search for keywords in the textbox, then changes the colour of this line and also a few other lines. e.g. search for the line that contains the word "video", if it returns that line 7 contains this word, I want to change the colour of line 7 and maybe lines 3, 10 and 11 to red colour.

Comment: Please understand that Stackoverflow isn't a code-it-for-me service. People here will be generous in helping you fix problems with code you've written but they won't write the code for you.

Answer (score 1):

Since your question is generic, We can only give a generic response.

First thing you need to know about VBA in powerpoint for your issue is that you need to access things like objects. You'll first need to access the current Slide and Shape your textbox is in. In this example, Let's assume the textbox you want to access is in the first slide, in the first shape:

```
Set oTextbox = ActivePresentation.Slides(1).Shapes(1)
With oTextbox
    text = .TextFrame.TextRange.Characters.Text 'To access the textbox text.
    If InStr(1,text,"some_text")
        .TextFrame.TextRange.Font.Color.RGB = [255 0 0] 'To change the color of a textbox.
    End If
End With
```

> `.TextFrame.TextRange.Characters.Text` accesses the shape's text.
>
> To search for a given text in the textbox, you can use the `InStr`
>   command to see if the text you want is in your textbox.
>
> `.TextFrame.TextRange.Font.Color.RGB` accesses the text's color.

This is at least a start for you.

Comment: Thanks medicine_man! I'll try it out when I get back at work.. this changes the text colour of the whole textbox?